# Imputation didn't work on missing values columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan, missing-data, fillna

I have this dataset for personal exercise, there are quite a lot of missing values in the dataset and since I wanted to do a model using this dataset, I tried to use imputation as follows:

```
flight_2['WORK_PROVINCE'].fillna(flight_2['WORK_PROVINCE'].mode(), inplace=True)
```

but when I did the fillna it didn't change/replace my missing values, when I check it:

```
flight_2['WORK_PROVINCE'].isna().sum()
```

the missing values stays at 3240

I'm expecting the missing values will be replaced by my fillna which is not

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and [edit] your question to include *all* necessary code and data to make it possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you already checked what the result of `flight_2['WORK_PROVINCE'].mode()` is?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.